# XPATH: How to select a grandparent's 3rd child element

Tags: selenium, xpath

Here is my DOM sample:

```
<div id="x-auto-2121" class="GI05A-4CEKC">
    <div class="GI05A-4CBKC GI05A-4COJC GI05A-4CGKC GI05A-4CFKC">
        <img style="height: 18px; width: 17px;" src="https://someserver.com/clear.gif"/>
        <img class="GI05A-4CDKC"/>
        <img class="GI05A-4CMJC"/>
        <img class="GI05A-4CCKC"/>
        <span class="GI05A-4CHKC">
            <span>The Unique Value I Can Search For</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know the value "The Unique Value I Can Search For" and can find it using something like this `//span[text()='The Unique Value I Can Search For']`

The problem is I want to select grandparent's third child:

```
 <img class="GI05A-4CMJC"/>
```

I 'm trying to use Selenium to test a UI that is extremely automation unfriendly (curse you, GXT). I am very new to xpath, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="x-auto-2121" class="GI05A-4CEKC">
    <div class="GI05A-4CBKC GI05A-4COJC GI05A-4CGKC GI05A-4CFKC">  <-- Common ancestor
        <img src="https://someserver.com/clear.gif"/>
        <img class="GI05A-4CDKC"/>
        <img class="GI05A-4CMJC"/>                                 <-- Node of interest
        <img class="GI05A-4CCKC"/>
        <span class="GI05A-4CHKC">
            <span>The Unique Value I Can Search For</span>         <-- Node of interest
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Approach one

Start with the key node, navigate up to the common ancestor of the nodes of interest, then dig down to the result. At the heart, we'll have

```
//span/../../img
```

Then it's question of specifying which `span` and which `img` we want.

```
//span[text()='The Unique Value I Can Search For']/../../img[3]
```

### Approach two

Start with the common ancestor of the nodes of interest, then dig down to the result. At the heart, we'll have

```
//div/img
```

Then it's question of specifying which `div` and which `img` we want.

```
//div[span/span/text()='The Unique Value I Can Search For']/img[3]
```

Comment: +1 A shorter equivalent XPath expression that could also be used: `//span[.='The Unique Value I Can Search For']/ancestor::div/img[3]`

Comment: @Mads Hansen, I forgot about `[3]`. Fixed. Using `ancestor` just to save characters is an awful idea. (Also, it actually adds 4 characters.)

Comment: But leaving out `/text()` would save some characters, i.e. `//div[span/span ='The Unique Value I Can Search For']/img[3]`.

Comment: can you help answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64585817/javascript-selector-find-checkbox-for-corresponding-sibling-text

Answer (score 0):

You can start xpath with tag having proper id. If the id is not dynamic, you can use the below xpath to get the required element.

```html
//div[@id='x-auto-2121']/div/img[3]
```