# Javascript Selector: Find Checkbox for corresponding Sibling Text

Tags: javascript

We are doing Test Automation. We need to locate elements under `kendo-grid-columnlist`, and given a Text Input (Product Type) in `Span`,  locate its corresponding `Input Checkbox`.

So if Requirements, is click checkbox for "Product Type," find the span ProductType,  and find its corresponding input. How can this be done with Javascript or Selenium FindElement Selector?

Input: "Product Type" under kendo-grid-columnlist

Output: Corresponding element for input checkbox

[image]

Comment: What are your trials to do this?

Comment: @Dev I am looking at this, still can't figure it out, https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-siblings/

Comment: Well you should add the selenium + javascript trials and errors in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
let spans = document.querySelectorAll('kendo-grid-columnlist .k-checkbox-label');
let myElement = null;
spans.forEach(item => {
        if(item.innerText === 'Product Type') {
            myElement = item.parentNode.firstElementChild;
        }
});
console.log(myElement);
```

Comment: I think this will be a better resource for learning xpath https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html